# Why am i getting a syntax error when running .kv file trying to link to class in .py file

Tags: python, kivy, syntax-error, typeerror

I apologize in advance, I am not sure how to properly format the code on my phone..

I saw I can comment it out... in the actual code there is no block comments just the line comments...

I am new to python. I want to try writing a simple mobile app and from my research I decided to use `kivy` so I can use the app on my `pc` as well.

I followed some `youtube` tutorials and when I am only using the `.py` file everything works fine.

I then wanted to move all my design elements to a `.kv` file to clean up the code.

I made a simple login screen...
2x labels, 2xTextimput and a button.

In the .py file I removed all the elements and was left with...

.............

#.py file

............

This runs fine when I change bookkeeping to bookkeep so that the .kv file is not called.

My .kv file I have also removed all the elements. I tried running it as...

............

#.kv file 1
............

And as

.............

.kv file 2

.............

When I run the .py file I get an error ending in...

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

And when i run the .kv file on its own I get error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>

    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)

  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start

    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)

  File "<string>", line 1

    <loginpage>

    ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Program finished]
```

I have tried different syntaxes, playing around with ' " and :

Still gets same error...

My .kv file is named bookkeeping.kv
It is saved in same folder as the .py file...

I am currently using pydroid3 on my phone... I have not tried running the code on pc yet...but if I can fix this on my phone it would be great...

#.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

#from kivy.uix.label import Label
#from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
#from kivy.uix.button import Button
#from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class loginpage(Widget):
    pass


class bookkeeping(App):
    def build(self):
        return loginpage()
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp=bookkeeping()
    MyApp.run()
```

#.kv file 1

```
<loginpage>

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
```

#.kv file 2

```
<loginpage>
```

I have also tried a few other syntaxes like:

```
<loginpage>:
<'loginpage'>
<"loginpage">:
```

Comment: Try renaming your classes to make them start with uppercase letter. Kivy is sensitive to this.

Comment: Hi there, I originally had it as LoginPage... this did not work then i made it loginpage also didnt work and now i tried Loginpage...still didnt work...the error points to the < so is there perhaps other brackets i need to use ??

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error you're facing suggests there might be a problem with how you are defining the layout in the `.kv` file.

Try this:

```
# bookkeeping.kv

<loginpage>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: 'Label 1'
        TextInput:
            hint_text: 'Input 1'
        Button:
            text: 'Submit'
```

You can replace the Labels and Inputs based on your requirements as well as add more if required.

This structure defines a `GridLayout` inside the `loginpage`, which includes labels, text inputs, and a button.

Additionally, in your `.py` file, you are using the class name `loginpage`, so ensure that the class name in the `.kv` file matches exactly:

```
# .py file

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder

# Load the .kv file
Builder.load_file('bookkeeping.kv')

class LoginPage(Widget):
    pass

class BookkeepingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginPage()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp = BookkeepingApp()
    MyApp.run()
```

The class name in the `.py` file is `LoginPage`, so it should match the class name in the `.kv` file.

Try these and run the code again.
Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Hi there ... i commented out my code completely and used yours... i just changed the class name so they match in the .py and .kv file..still no luck... could it be pydroid3 self?? Ill try and run it on pc

Comment: @Suzanne1998 Are you getting any error? Did you ensure that both the files are in the same location?

Comment: Both files are in same location and .kv file is all lover case letters....keep getting the same error messages on the .py file i only get an error message when i actually refer to the .kv file(i tested it when i rename my app so that it does not try to load the .kv file...then the .py file works ... so i am 100% sure its the .kv file.i get that error that i put in my description...basically saying its a syntax error and i have tried writing it with different capitalization with and without ' & " &  : ..the error points to the < bracket but according to me my notation and indentation is correct

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT WORKING!!!

I ended up writing a similar test program on vsCode...

I had a problem where the window opened but no widgets where displaying.

The solution on vsCode was basically the following:

.py file...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class NameChanger(App):
    def build(self):
        pass

class Window(Widget):
    def callback(self,instance):
        print('Hello world')

if __name__=='__main__':
    NameChanger().run()
```

.kv file...

```
<Window>

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    size: root.width, root.height

    Label:
        text: 'Hello World'
        font_size: 36
    
    TextInput:
    
    Button:
        text: 'This is a button'
        size_hint: 1, 0.5
        bold: True
        italic: True

    Label:
        text: 'Problem solved!'
```

I then tried to run this code on pydroid and it worked!!!

It also works with

```
<Window>:
```

But seems the indent before the GridLayout was causing the problem...

New code for the file in my Question:

.py file...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class BookkeepingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        pass

class LoginPage(Widget):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BookkeepingApp().run()
```

.kv file...

```
<LoginPage>

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    
    Label:
        text: 'IT WORKS!'
```

Note: When i was writing on the pc i had some code in the .kv file that was commented out wit """......""" for block comment in python.
I believe this is also part of the problem as after i fixed the indentation before the GridLayout i was getting new errors related to the """ and after removing the block comment it worked...

Similarly on my phone even after fixing the root problem i got new error related to indentation for my Label... I believe because I just used enter to go down it was aligning correctly according to the eye but I had 2 indents before my text: for the Label instead of one...(difficult to explain like this) but basically instead of just entering i had to enter and go back one tab...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pydroid 3 do **not** run the `My.kv` file. Just write the code in that file and save it and then come your original python file `main.py` and add a command in that just after importing the modules.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file('path/of/My.kv')
```

Make sure you have installed buildozer in your device if don't just run this command in terminal:

```
pip install buildozer
```

Then just that `main.py` file also. Finally run the `.python` file and you get your output.